# MySQL CPU Peak when Insert Query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, optimization

I have running ASP script with MYSQL.

Server is Xeon E3 1230v / 32 GB RAM / 2 x 120 GB SSD (Raid 0)

There are 2 virtual machines installed 1 - windows 2008 for ASP and 1- CentOS for MySQL

When i reach 200+ Online systems works fine until i run a insert or update query.

After that cpu usage goes top 95+% for a while and then it goes back to normal.

Also I have some sleep processes in the process list. This web site is growing rapidly so i need to solve this problem quick. For now it has max. 400 online users.

I have tried lots of things to solve this problem but still no luck.

What can you suggest to solve this problem? What may be the reason for this?

Any help appreciated.

[statistics http://www.extraimg.net/?di=XK9S](http://www.extraimg.net/?di=XK9S)

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

Tables

[ex http://www.extraimg.net/?di=QZWR](http://www.extraimg.net/?di=QZWR)

There are no triggers. When i check phpMyAdmin > DB > Triggers.

[ex http://www.extraimg.net/?di=7IV7](http://www.extraimg.net/?di=7IV7)

Comment: Is this for all tables or just one? What (if any) indexes and triggers do you have set up, and what table type are you using (InnoDB, MYISAM etc)

Comment: I think visualization is the main culprit. Why dont you install mysql on windows only?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. :) 

I have added screenshot for tables and indexes.. I think it happens for all. Also there are no triggers. @Re0sless

Comment: I don't think virtualisation is the problem. Because it was even worse before i did that. It helped for a while. When i had 50-100 online i got this problem and i did virtualisation.. Now i have 300+ and this problem started to occur again. @Ratna

Comment: it is weired, it usually happens the other way round..anyway does the slow update/insert query has any thing to do with no of sleep queries?Also double check the odbc driver version try to use the latest, also are there any slow_log queries?

Comment: I don't think update/insert queries has anything to do with no of sleep queries. Because insert and update queries are too rare.
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver} -> Should i change this?
Also slow_log query was off i did this; SET GLOBAL log_slow_queries =  "ON" @Ratna

Comment: use 5.1 driver when connecting to mysql 5.X for better optimasion